# React object won't update after biding to redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react component with the following constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    url: props.url,
    status: props.status
  }
  ...
}
```

And the following span tag:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="ConnectionPanel">
      ...
      <span>{this.state.status}</span>
      ...
    </div>      
  )
}
```

And my `mapStateToProps` looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  url: state.websocket.url,
  status: state.websocket.status  
})
```

The initial value of `state.websocket.status` gets rendered, but when it's updated from outside the `span` tag is not.

I can't figure out why is my way of binding is incorrect, and how to fix it.

Comment: you should avoid internal state while using state managers (eg, redux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely you aren't updating your `state` when the `props` get updated. You could use a lifecycle method to handle this, but the better way is to just use `props` in the first place.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="ConnectionPanel">
      ...
      <span>{this.props.status}</span>
      ...
    </div>      
  )
}
```